# Alternative to Rx (Reactive Extensions) for .net 3.5

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm working on a .net 3.5 app and I'd like to know if there is a workaround or other software that can provide similar functionality to IObservable and especially Observable.FromEvent

The app runs inside mediabrowser so I absolutely have to stay with .net 3.5 otherwise I'd happily upgrade to 4.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont need 4.0 if you want RX. You can have RX for 3.5